# SQL - Comparing Dates in 2 Tables, Retrieving Most Recent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two large MS SQL Server tables (`A & B`) that I'll generalize here. I'm attempting to create a new column in `TableA` derived from `TableB`, containing the most recent `TableB.refDate` PRIOR to each row's `TableA.dataDate`. Extremely large datasets, but these `DISTINCT` date queries run quickly. Simply concerned with the distinct dates in each table, no further matching criteria required.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dataDate FROM TableA
> 2019-02-13
> 2019-02-09
> 2019-02-05

SELECT DISTINCT refDate FROM TableB
> 2019-02-13
> 2019-02-12
> 2019-02-10
> 2019-02-07
> 2019-02-05
> 2019-02-04
```

The end result should be something like:

```
dataDate     mostRecentRefDate
2019-02-13   2019-02-12
2019-02-09   2019-02-07
2019-02-05   2019-02-04
```

Something along these lines should work in theory, but the datasets are far too large:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT a.dataDate as dataDate,
(SELECT MAX(b.refDate) FROM TableB b WHERE a.dataDate > b.refDate) as mostRecentRefDate
FROM TableA a
```

Is there a better way to perform this utilizing the results of those initial `DISTINCT` date queries? Then reference the results to quickly insert the new column?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
SELECT
  a.dataDate as dataDate,
  MAX(b.refDate) mostRecentRefDate
FROM TableA a,
inner join TableB b 
  on a.dataDate > b.refDate
group by a.dataDate
```

Comment: you should do this against CTEs or derived tables selecting the DISTINCT date and hopefully they will be spooled. If it hits the big tables directly this wont scale as rows processed will be the two table rows multiplied and divided by two

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want other columns besides the dates, I would recommend `apply`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a outer apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from b
      where b.refdate < a.datadate
      order by b.refdate desc
     ) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
WITH T(date, source) AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT dataDate, 'A' 
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT refDate, 'B'
FROM TableB
), T2 AS
(
SELECT   * ,
         mostRecentRefDate = MAX(CASE WHEN source = 'B' THEN date END) 
                        OVER (ORDER BY date, source ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM     T
)
SELECT date AS dataDate, mostRecentRefDate
FROM T2
WHERE source = 'A'
```

The plan for this looks pretty good (though yours may differ depending on how the `DISTINCT` is carried out)

[image]